# Using mockito to mock AsyncTask results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-asynctask

I am having a hard time mocking an AsyncTask with Mockito on Android. This test fails as a result of a NullPointerException.

Here is my test. I tried running it on the UI thread;

```
@UiThreadTest
public void testWhenUpdatingContent_ShouldExecuteContentUpdater() {
    ContentUpdater contentUpdaterMock = mock(ContentUpdater.class);
    ContentExtractor contentExtractorMock = mock(ContentExtractor.class);
    ContentManager contentManager = new ContentManager(contentUpdaterMock, contentExtractorMock);

    contentManager.updateContent();

    verify(contentUpdaterMock).execute(contentExtractorMock);
}
```

Here is ContentManager's very simple code;

```
public class ContentManager {

    private ContentUpdater contentUpdater;
    private ContentExtractor contentExtractor;

    public ContentManager(ContentUpdater contentUpdater, ContentExtractor contentExtractor) {
        this.contentUpdater = contentUpdater;
        this.contentExtractor = contentExtractor;
    }

    public void updateContent() {

        contentUpdater.execute(contentExtractor);
    }
}
```

The exception occurs on `contentUpdater.execute(...)`. I don't even get why `execute(...)` gets called as `contentUpdater` is mocked, which really seems to be my problem.

Here is the stacktrace;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:574)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
at com.axis4.adder_ladder.ContentManager.updateContent(ContentManager.java:15)
at com.axis4.adder_ladder.test.ContentManagerTest.testWhenUpdatingContent_ShouldExecuteContentUpdater(ContentManagerTest.java:22)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.access$000(InstrumentationTestCase.java:36)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase$2.run(InstrumentationTestCase.java:189)
at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:1719)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

`execute()` is a *final* method and cannot be mocked (without bytecode manipulation, e.g. with PowerMock).

```
public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> execute(Params... params) {
    return executeOnExecutor(sDefaultExecutor, params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You may choose to use  [Powermock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock), which uses a special classloader to rewrite the old behavior, or [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/), which does the same but replaces classes with Android-specific test-friendly alternate implementations ("shadows") [including one for AsyncTask.](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAsyncTask.html)

**see**
[Why doesn't mocking work with AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556172/why-doesnt-mocking-work-with-asynctask)